# Calling a Java method (dealing with generics) from Scala failed

Tags: java, scala, generics

I want to call this Java method (part of an API), from Scala (2.10.3):

```
public <R> ConvertedResult<R> to(Class<R> type,
    ResultConverter<Map<String, Object>, R> converter)
```

`ResultConverter` interface being:

```
public interface ResultConverter<T, R> {
    R convert(T value, Class<R> type);
}
```

First, I created my converter (in Scala so):

```
class MyVOConverter extends ResultConverter[Map[String, AnyRef], MyVO] {

    def convert(queryResult: Map[String, AnyRef], 
                `type`: Class[MyVO]): MyVO = {
       //...
    }
}
```

providing a type and my `MyVOConverter` like this, when the call is made:

```
myResult.to(classOf[MyVO], new MyVOConverter())
```

However, Scala compiler warns about this:

```
Type mismatch, expected: ResultConverter[Map[String, AnyRef], NotInferedR],
actual: MyVOConverter
```

How to deal with this case?

Comment: Did you try `to[MyVO](classOf...)`?

Comment: @Rex Kerr I've just tried it, but now it complains about the method `to` itself: `cannot resolved symbol to`.  Here what I've just tested: `myResult.to[MyVO](classOf[MyVO], new MyVOConverter())`

Comment: Oh, I guess `<R>` is from the enclosing class?  Maybe you can insist to the enclosing class that its type parameter is `MyVO`?

Comment: @RexKerr With that syntax, `R` should be a parameter of the method.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the javadoc of the API you are using?

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral I use this API: https://github.com/neo4j/java-rest-binding/blob/master/src/main/java/org/neo4j/rest/graphdb/query/RestQueryResult.java
Concerned interface is:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/3.0.0.M1/api/org/springframework/data/neo4j/conversion/Result.html

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral - That's what I thought, but I was wondering if I was misremembering somehow.  Since it doesn't make any sense to not be able to see the method.

Comment: `import java.util.{ Map => JMap }` and replace `Map` with `JMap` as Daniel suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Map` on the interface is `java.util.Map`, but, assuming you haven't imported that, you are using `scala.collection.immutable.Map` and, therefore, incompatible.